# Securing Microservices with NGINX Reverse Proxy and (Custom) Authentication Server

Tags: authentication, nginx, microservices, grpc

I have a micro-service architecture where Flutter clients send HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 (gRPC) requests to different microservices. I have implemented a routing mechanism to direct incoming requests to the appropriate microservice. To enhance security, I have included an authentication server that verifies all incoming requests. Each request is accompanied by a JWT (JSON Web Token) for authentication. The authentication process functions correctly when tested independently, without being behind an NGINX reverse proxy. However, when I use an NGINX reverse proxy, the authentication does not work as expected.

Configuration for HTTP requests is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 8000 http;
    server_name example.server;
    

    //Other configs

    # HTTP2 Authentication End Point
    location /auth {
        internal;
        grpc_pass grpc://authentication_http2;
        grpc_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        grpc_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        grpc_set_header X-Auth-Response $http_x_auth_response;
        error_page 401 = /auth_error;
    }

    location /package.Service {
        auth_request /auth
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        if ($auth_status = 200) {
            grpc_pass grpc://microservice1;
        }
        error_page 401 = /auth_error;
    }

    location /auth_error {
        return 401 "Authentication Error";
    }
}
```

And for the Http/2 request

```
server {
    listen 8001 http2;
    server_name example.server;

    //Other configs

    # HTTP2 Authentication End Point
    location /authentication.AuthenticationService/AuthenticateWithJWT {
        internal;
        grpc_pass grpc://authentication_http2;
        grpc_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        grpc_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        grpc_set_header X-Auth-Response $http_x_auth_response;
        error_page 401 = /auth_error;
    }

    location /package.Service {
        if ($auth_status = 200) {
            grpc_pass grpc://microservice1;
        }
        error_page 401 = /auth_error;
    }

    location /auth_error {
        return 401 "Authentication Error";
    }
}
```

Access.log has the following line
`127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jul/2023:15:46:04 +0530] "POST /package.Service/Func HTTP/2.0" 500 186 "-" "grpc-node-js/1.8.10"`

Error.log has the following line.
`2023/07/13 15:46:04 [error] 53108#53108: *3 auth request unexpected status: 405 while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: genesis.engine, request: "POST /package.Service/Func HTTP/2.0", host: "localhost:8001"`

I am currently facing a challenge with authenticating HTTP2 requests in my microservice architecture.  I am unsure how to extend this authentication mechanism to gRPC calls.

I am seeking guidance or a tutorial that can help me understand how to authenticate gRPC calls using NGINX and if there is any alternative to the `auth_request` directive, as it is not doesn't work for grpc calls. I would appreciate any assistance or information that can point me in the right direction to resolve this issue.

I am trying to make things work only using NGINX OSS.